# Meteor Create HelloWorld

Tags: node.js

These are the steps I am executing:

```
# meteor create helloworld

# cd helloworld

# meteor
```

Terminal displays `Running on: http://localhost:3000/`

I point the browser to `http://localhost:3000/`

Everything looks ok in the browser, I see **Hello World!**. I click on the **[Click]** button. Nothing happens, no alert in browser. I switch to the terminal anticipating to see **You pressed the button** but all I see is `Running on: http://localhost:3000/` I don't see **You pressed the button** anywhere in client or server.

So in *helloworld.js*, what is the following code snippet supposed to do?

```
Template.hello.events = {
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  };
}
```

My best guess is in the terminal below the line `Running on: http://localhost:3000/` **You pressed this button** will appear everytime I click on the button but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the console in your browser. If you're using Chrome access the console using Tools -> Javascript Console. You'll see tabs like Elements, Resources... Go to the last one 'Console'. You could also use Ctrl+Shift+J to access the Javascript console.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the explanation found at: [Extremely Gentle Introduction to Meteor.js](http://www.sympodial.com/blog/an-extremely-gentle-introduction-to-meteor.html)

it looks like that part of the code is actually executed on the client's side and would show up in your browser's javascript console, and not on the server.

Pay attention to the fact that your code is wrapped in:

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {
   ...
}
```